# Installing php_svn.dll extension in the Zend Server CE

Tags: php, svn, php-extension

I've been trying to add the **php_svn.dll** extension into the zend server for a few days now.

Below is my setup:

> **Zend Server Community Edition**: 5.5.0
>
> **PHP**:5.3.8-ZS5.5.0
>
> **Web Server Server Software**: Apache/2.2.16 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.16 OpenSSL/0.9.8o
>
> **Zend Framework**: 1.11.10

I used the zend server CE installer to set up my stack.

As for retrieving the **php_svn.dll**, because http://pecl.php.net/package/svn is not available (not to mention hosts thread-safe extensions - which are incompatible to zend), I basically had to build from source a non thread safe version of PHP and the SVN extension. (Like the zend stack, the PHP source is 5.3.8 as well)

To build PHP I followed the steps in https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild. And to build the SVN extension, I ensured that I had the dependencies asked for in the extension's config.w32. Things seem to have gone smoothly here because I managed to get a **php_svn.dll**.

I then copy-pasted the resulting **php_svn.dll** from `<php_source_dir>\Release\` into my `<zend_install_dir>\ZendServer\lib\phpext\` and added the new .dll in **php.ini** file hoping things would finally work. However, when I restarted the zend server, I got the following log-entry:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   'C:\zend\ZendServer\lib\phpext\php_svn.dll' - The specified module
>   could not be found.  in Unknown on line 0

Am I missing anything here?

**EDIT**

I figured it out!

The next step here was to simply take the ***.dll*** equivalents of the svn extension's **.lib** dependencies and place them onto the ZendServer's bin directory.